# Chapter 8.2 - @current_user or current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm reading Michael Hartl's tutorial about RoR, chapter 8. I wrote these methods:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end
end
```

This code works fine. I tried to get rid of the `current_user` method, and changed the code to the following:

```
module SessionsHelper
  def login(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end

  def logged_in?
    !(@current_user.nil?)
  end
end
```

When I call `logged_in?`, it always returns `false`. Why do I need to call `current_user` method to access `@current_user`? `@current_user` should be available in all methods of this module because it is an instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't ever call the `current_user` method, then `@current_user` will never be initialized (assigned a value). So whenever you refer to `@current_user`, it will be `nil`. In other words, `logged_in?`, or `!(@current_user.nil?)` will be `false`.

Comment: I assigned @current_user = User.find_by(id: session[:user_id]) in the login method

Comment: Is `login` always called before you call `logged_in?`?

Comment: No it isn't. I thought @current_user would be available because it is an instance variable..

Comment: Read my answer again carefully.